# print weather update in tkinter Gui interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print the condition weather on tkinter gui interface.So I wrote this code....

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from weather import Weather,Unit

win=tk.Tk()

weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
location=weather.lookup_by_location('Dhaka')
condition=location.condition
label=Label(text=condition)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

But the output sample is...
[image: This is my unexpected output]

But I want output that show condition like Sunny,Thunderstorm etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've linked the object to a label, you need to call the text. `condition.text`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from weather import Weather,Unit

win=tk.Tk()

weather = Weather(unit=Unit.CELSIUS)
location=weather.lookup_by_location('Dhaka')
condition=location.condition
label=Label(text=condition.text)
label.pack()

win.mainloop()
```